# MediaPlayer not working on some android devices

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play the mp3 file from web using media player class , on some devices it is working fine but for few devices it is giving following error .

QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
Unable to create media player
error (-38, 0)
Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

any help on this will be of great help.

Comment: did you use `setOnErrorListener` if not try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29

Answer (score 0):

In general error -38 means you are trying to call a function in wrong state for the player.

In your case as error says, you call `getDuration()` when player is not prepared or started. Set `setOnPreparedListener()` then start the player `mp.start()`, then you can call `getDuration()`.

Check this [Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778) to stream audio from web